# soql query to retrieve nearby vendors for an account

Tags: soql, geolocation

I have a request to show nearby vendors for a customer account.

I am using the Account object to store both the customer accounts and the vendor accounts. but with different record types which are customer_account & vendor_account.

To store the address info for these accounts I use the BillingAddress field for the customer accounts and the ShippingAddress field for the vendors.

I have activated the Data integration rules for populating the geolocation data for all of these accounts.

Now my question is how to retrieve vendors that is closer to a customer account using SOQL?

I am looking at this soql, but cant really make out to apply the same for my situation. I believe here the BillingAddress field is my customer address and the geolocation fields latitude and longitude fields are for the vendors. Also I would be binding variables for the geolocation fields.

```
SELECT Id, Name, BillingAddress
FROM Account
WHERE DISTANCE(BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(37.775,-122.418), 'mi') < 20 
ORDER BY DISTANCE(BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(37.775,-122.418), 'mi')
LIMIT 10
```

And this is what I have tried and I get a malformed query error on workbench and developer console

```
SELECT Name, BillingLatitude, ShippingLatitude FROM Account WHERE DISTANCE(BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(ShippingLatitude, ShippingLongitude),'mi') AND Id ='0013453453543453'
```

Comment: You'll need to have the GEOLOCATION populated from your Customer Account's geoposition `BillingLatitude` and `BillingLongitude` fields (via first querying then binding these) and use the Vendor Account's Shipping location, probably via `GEOLOCATION(ShippingLatitude, ShippingLongitude)` - not sure since I've only done this with custom Location fields previously - or perhaps with just `ShippingAddress` (similar to what you tried).

Comment: @PhilW My customer accounts already have the geopositions populated. I just dont know how to correctly use them in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOQL cannot dynamically compare field values with other field values, and it is not possible for a SOQL query to use details from one record while querying other records without these values being explicitly passed in (as literal values or bindings).

From what you said, you are looking for Vendor Accounts that are close to a specific Customer Account.

In this example, I have assumed you have queried the Customer Account's Billing Latitude and Longitude already:

```
Account customer = [SELECT BillingLatitude, BillingLongitude, ... FROM Account WHERE ...];

Location customerLocation = Location.newInstance(customer.BillingLatitude, customer.BillingLongitude);

List<Account> vendors = [
    SELECT Id, ...
        FROM Account
        WHERE ... // probably check the record type
            AND DISTANCE(ShippingAddress, :customerLocation, 'mi') < 20
            ...
];
```

I have omitted things like the ordering or returning that distance value, but what this does to is outline the Apex you need. Note the use of a `Location` instance, which is equivalent to `GEOLOCATION` but lets me deal with the customer geolocation in static SOQL.

Comment: Thanks Phil W. I have just added some code to the original post after my testing. Could you please have a look?

Comment: You probably have your own class, or a variable, called `Location` that is shadowing the real class.

Comment: No it is just a fresh implementation of Salesforce. Just started creating a few things on it.

Comment: That seems odd. Can you include the exact and complete error message please?

Comment: here is the complete error message `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void newInstance(String, String) from the type System.Location (10:50)`

Comment: Ah, OK. That is because your `Request` declares the latitude and longitude properties to be `String` instead of `Double` - these are numbers. Look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Account.htm). BTW, you really should have opened a separate question instead of updating this one because it makes the answer not quite align with the question now.

Comment: Phil W. I will create another question and let you know soon. If possible please have this answer added there.

Comment: here is the link to the new story https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/415490/using-location-object-to-create-a-new-instance-of-a-location-error-out