# Using location object to create a new Instance of a location error out

Tags: geolocation

I am trying to make it as an Apex invocable method action to find the nearby vendors based on the customers address. When trying to push the code to my instance I get an error on the line **location.newInstance**, it says method does not exist or incorrect signature.

```
public with sharing class GetNearbyVendorsService {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Get Nearby Vendors' description='Apex action to pull information on Nearby Vendors')
    public static List<Results> getNearbyVendors(List<Requests> input) {

        List<Id> ids = new List<Id>();
        List<Location> locations = new List<Location>();
        for (Requests request : input) {
            Requests inputRequest = request;
            
            Location customerLocation = Location.newInstance(inputRequest.billingLatitude, inputRequest.billingLongitude);
            locations.add(customerLocation);
            ids.add(inputRequest.veteranId);
        }
        System.debug(input);

        List<Account> vendors = new List<Account>();
        vendors = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingAddress FROM Account
        WHERE Id IN :ids AND DISTANCE(ShippingAddress, :locations[0], 'mi') < 20 
        ORDER BY DISTANCE(ShippingAddress, :locations[0], 'mi')
        LIMIT 10];

        List<Results> results = new List<Results>();

        Results result = new Results();
        result.vendors = vendors;
        result.status = 'pass';
        result.errorMessage = '';
        results.add(result);      
        return results;

    }
    public class Requests {
        @InvocableVariable(label='Veteran Id' required=true)
        public String veteranId;
        @InvocableVariable(label='Latitude' required=true)
        public String billingLatitude;
        @InvocableVariable(label='Longitude' required=true)
        public String billingLongitude;
     }

     public class Results {
 
        @InvocableVariable(label='Vendor Accounts' required=true)
        public List<Account> vendors;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Status' required=true)
        public String status; 

        @InvocableVariable(label='Error Message' required=true)
        public String errorMessage;
     }
}
```

Comment: here is the complete error message Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void newInstance(String, String) from the type System.Location (10:50)

Comment: Have you tried just using `Location customerLocation = new Location(BillingLatitude = inputRequest.billingLatitude, BillingLongitude = inputRequest.billingLongitude); `

Comment: @CallumMacErlich. Phil W had an answer for this on this ticket https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/415313/soql-query-to-retrieve-nearby-vendors-for-an-account. I just separated the tickets.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_location.htm) shows that Latitude and Longitude values must be `Double`, not `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DavidCheng correctly pointed out the type for lat/long fields is Double, not String, but this code has them as strings.

The property types should be changed from String to Double OR Double.valueOf should be used to convert the properties to the correct type when passing to the `Location.newInstance` method.

I recommend the former approach:

```
    public class Requests {
        @InvocableVariable(label='Veteran Id' required=true)
        public String veteranId;
        @InvocableVariable(label='Latitude' required=true)
        public Double billingLatitude;
        @InvocableVariable(label='Longitude' required=true)
        public Double billingLongitude;
    }
```

You may need to tweak your flow a little as well.